# C: How do I round a global variable?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, global-variables, rounding, compile-time

I have the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double x = round(3.2/2.0);

int main()
{
    printf("%f", x);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the error **initializer element is not a compile-time constant**. Without `round`, it compiles without a hitch.

I want to round x while having it as a global variable. Is this possible?

Comment: If you know the exact value, (round(3.2 / 2.0) = 2.0), why would you even want to make such a calculation in code? And not just `double x = 2.0 // Got this value from round(3.2 / 2.0)`?

Comment: Interestingly, GCC only emits a warning instead of an error and when ` __builtin_round` is used, it doesn't even do that. But I guess (and somewhat hope) non-portable GCC-only code is a no-go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C language objects with static storage duration can only be initialized with *integral constant expressions*. You are not allowed to call any functions in integral constant expressions.

You will have to find a way to generate your value through an integral constant expression. Something like this might work

```
double x = (int) (3.2 / 2.0 + 0.5);
```

Comment: Note: This approach usually works except for 1) only in range of `int` or `long long` or whatever integer cast used, 2) Only in positive range as code should be `- 0.5` when pre-rounded value is negative 3) "+0.5 and cast" always rounds positive ties (halfway) up whereas `round(some_FP)` may round some ties down.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a function in the global scope, try

```
#include <math.h>

double x;
int main(void) 
 {
    x = round(3.2 / 2.0);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Why `1.5` instead of `3.2/2.0`?

Comment: I just used a random value, to illustrate.